# How to put files into the image more conveniently?

Tags: linux, images

I have an image file `boot-exit.img`.

```
$ file boot-exit.img
boot-exit.img: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

I want to put files into this image .
This is too much trouble. I always move the local `run.sh` to the `/home` folder inside the image.
I just need to modify the local run.sh.
I can now transfer files by mounting.

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=$((512*2048)) boot-exit.img /mnt/rootfs/
cp run.sh images_destination_folder
sudo umount /mnt/rootfs
```

But it seems a bit redundant to mount the directory every time.
I tried some other commands.

```
sudo e2cp -p run.sh boot-exit.img:/home

Bad magic number in super-block
Bad magic number in super-block
Error opening destination boot-exit.img:boot-exit.img
```

Note that I need to set the offset when mounting, otherwise this problem will also occur. This seems to be the cause of the file format.

Is there any better way?

Thanks

Comment: If your goal is just to update a single file in the disk image, I believe that your method is already near the most efficient or convenient. Improvements can be achieved by using a root shell (avoiding the sudo), by using a local dir to mount and by preparing a script that does all the work in short command.

Comment: If this single file update is part of larger development cycle, maybe some shortcuts can be selected in the whole testing cycle. If you need to install the disk image file into a storage device, the you can try to update the device directly.